# How to resolve "Visual Studio exe file not finding resources"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on a C++ Visual Studio project and the issue I am facing is that when I build my project and then run the exe file (not the project). It is not able to gather all the files (images, txt files, etc) that I am using. It is not an issue when I run the project inside VS (but it doesn't work when I run the exe).

I think I know why it is not working: I would have to move the exe to the same directory as my resources. But is there anyway to not do this and avoid any movement of files or the exe? All the resources I am accessing are relative to the project directory:

```
- Project Dir
  - res
    - testimg.png
  - bin
    - intermediates
    - Win32
      - Release
        - program.exe
```

(In Code):

```
const char* imgpath = "res/testimg.png"
```

(and so on for other files as well...)

My goal is to make this portable so that if I build this project on another machine, I can simply click on the exe and run it without any issue. That is why I have also set up all the header files utility code via $(SolutionDir) and $(ProjectDir) macros instead of providing absolute paths.

Comment: windows executable files support a mechanism for resources. you can pack the images and the other files inside the exe and then it'll always be able to find them

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to automate this process? Because essentially what I want is to use a software like premake or cmake to build the project on another machine and run it without manually doing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* imgpath = "res/testimg.png"
```

I created a Win32 project that loads images, generated an exe file. And I put the Release file and res in the Project Dir provided above.

In my test, it should be

```
const char* imgpath = "../../res/testimg.png"
```